# Can a convert be considered in-law after the conversion?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, family-members, parashas-yisro

I was taught that a convert loses his relations after conversion:
"גר שהתגייר כתינוק שנולד".

First, after Tzipora allegedly converted Yitro is no longer her father in relation to anything Halachic, and therefore not Moses's in-law. After the second round of Yitro's conversion he "lost it once more".

However, in Parshas Yitro, he is continuously referred by the Torah and the interpreters as Moses's in-law. Moses is also showing a great deal of respect, because of him being his relative - and not because of הכרת הטוב only.

How these interpretations can be explained in contrary to the accepted Halachah?

Comment: Consider that conversions before *matan Torah* were not as formal as after, and rules regarding family members were not necessarily as with our converts

Comment: @mbloch Please continue... meaning what?

Comment: Meaning it is possible Yitro converted but kept his family relations, and Moshe kept relating to him with the *kavod* due to the father of his wife (which Yitro remained). I don't think Yitro immersed in a *mikve*, got a *brit* etc. in front of a *beit din*. This probably came later. I have no sources for this yet - which is why I wrote "Consider"

Comment: This calls forth 2 issues -- one is the nature of "marriage" before matan torah and the second is whether there is any religious significance to being labeled a father-in-law or if that is simply a fact based on common understanding, not a religious signifier.

Comment: Naomi is called Ruth's mother in law even after Machlon died. Maybe it doesn't mean Halakhic relation as regards geneology